# Conditional Check Prerequisite while installation using Wix installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have taken a CheckBox control in wix installer to prompt user 
Do you want to make this Machine as Server ?
if user ticks, then I have to check SQL Server is installed or not.

```
<Property Id="IsServerMachine" Value="0" />

<!--check if SQL service is running on Machine, if not, show message and exit-->
<Property Id="MSSQLSERVER_INSTALLED" >
  <RegistrySearch Id="IsSqlServerServiceInstalled" Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSSQLSERVER" Name="DisplayName" Type="raw"/>
</Property>
<Property Id="MSSQL_SQLEXPRESS_INSTALLED" >
  <RegistrySearch Id="IsSqlExpressServiceInstalled" Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS" Name="DisplayName" Type="raw"/>
</Property>
<Condition Message="SQL not installed">Installed OR MSSQLSERVER_INSTALLED OR MSSQL_SQLEXPRESS_INSTALLED OR IsServerMachine=1</Condition>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem. Also, what is your question?

Comment: My Question is : I have taken 1 checkbox in dialog page for asking user to make this machine as Server, if user checks then I want to execute database script. How can I make this decision to custom installation ? In which section I have to write the code ?